# How to synchronise pip libraries with PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I just recently switched to Python and started using Pycharm. I have installed 'rumps' library but when I tried to import it in PyCharm, the app says library not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean via `pip install ...` in cmd or terminal? or Via PyCharms `settings` options?

Comment: i installed it via pip install

Comment: Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: pip list - it's there

Comment: Run the program and post the error. Sometimes you have to restart PyCharm for the debugger to work properly, but if it is installed it should work regardless of what PyCharm tells you.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 "/Users/Artem/PycharmProjects/RSScan v0.1/Core.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Artem/PycharmProjects/RSScan v0.1/Core.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rumps
ImportError: No module named 'rumps'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Changed to Python 2.7 - all works